# Exchange 2007 search message log for a list of wildcard domains?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying to do a search through our Exchange 2007 system for all emails from 8 different domains.

So far I've managed to get this working:

Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start "01/01/2014" -End "19/06/2014" | where{$*.sender -like "*@example.com"} | select-object Timestamp,SourceContext,Source,EventId,MessageSubject,Sender,{$*.Recipients} | export-csv C:\ExchangeLogResults.txt

But what I'd like is to be able to change the "where" clause to something like a get-content, eg:

Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start "01/01/2014" -End "19/06/2014" | where{$_.sender -like (get-content .\list_of_domains.txt)} | select-object Timestamp,SourceContext,Source,EventId,MessageSubject,Sender,{$_.Recipients} | export-csv C:\temp\ExchangeLogResults.txt

With the list_of_domains.txt having the list of domains that I'm interested in.

When I run the second script I don't get any results, but when I run the single wildcarded domain I get loads.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can't use -like that way.

I do this kind of filtering by building a regex from the list of domains, and then using -match:

```
$DomainList = get-content .\list_of_domains.txt 

[regex]$dom_rgx = "`(?i)(?:" + (($DomainList |% {"@" + [regex]::escape($_)}) -join "|") + ")$"

Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start "01/01/2014" -End "19/06/2014" |
 where{$_.sender -match $dom_rgx} | 
 select-object Timestamp,SourceContext,Source,EventId,MessageSubject,Sender,{$_.Recipients} |
 export-csv
```

Comment: OK that makes sense, I didn't think of using a regex. With regards to your "list_of_domains.txt" what would you think the list should look like? Is it just simply the list e.g.:

example.com
test.com
etc...

The only reason I ask is because the working example for a single domain looks like this "*@example.com" so I would need to append the long list with the quotes, a * and the @. Is that possible?
Thanks again
Andrew

Comment: Just create a list of domain names like "example.com".   The script will add the @ before each one.  You don't want to add a * (that's appropriate for a wildcard filter using -like, but not for a regex using -match).  I wrote an article that explains the regex construction bits if you're interested: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx

Comment: Cool!  If you don't mind, mark this as Answered, so it doesn't show up in the Unaswered Questions.